# Ranking with 2 URLs for one keyword | Category page & all product page | Use canonical?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I have a webshop where I have a category page called 'Smartwatch'. On this page I inform but also inspire people about smartwatches. 
Page title of this page : *Smartwatch | Find your Smartwatch.*

Next to this page I also have another page called 'Smartwatch'. This page displays all the smartwatch products. 
Page title of this page: *Smarthwatch | Look at all Smartwatches.*

Now when I check the SERP I see both pages rank. The category pages ranks #8 and the product list page ranks #9 with the search query 'Smartwatch'.

I assume that I could rank better when all 'SEO value' is pointed to one URL. I could do this with a canonical towards one URL. The problem with this is that the content of the two URLs is not exactly the same. However you can argue that the intention is the same.

Does anyone have an idea what to do in this situation? Changing the robots to (noindex, follow) or (noindex, nofollow) would be not the correct solution since it would mean a loss of link value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If two pages can become one**

The best solution here is to only have 1 page. So if you can merge the category page and product list page that would be best. Put a 301-redirect from page A to page B, page B being the page that ranks best for that keyword. Verify that using Google Search Console. Doing this will lead to consolidating the authority both pages have.

**Alternative #1**

If it's not possible to merge the pages and they should coexist, my next thought would be: create more distance between the two pages in terms of keyword focus. Perhaps combine one of the pages with another keyword so they stop being relevant for the same keyword?

**Alternative #2**

Third option: use a canonical instead of a noindex, since canonical URLs pass on some link authority [(more info here)](https://www.becontentking.com/academy/canonical/#consolidating-link-authority-only-partially). Nonindex will just mean the page will be removed from the index, and all link authority will be lost.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Indeed, your alternative #2 is what I mentioned ;). I will start testing with using a canonical. Thanks!